# Let's get critical: Jul 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Software Quality Assurance & Testing Stack Exchange](http://sqa.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6057/test-scenarios-for-an-advertising-identifier-used-for-an-ios-app

  **Net Score: -6** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 6)
- [Selenium WebDriver | Unable to switch to apparent pop-up](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6050/selenium-webdriver-unable-to-switch-to-apparent-pop-up)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [API Automated Testing Tool XML & JSON](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6072/api-automated-testing-tool-xml-json)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Any good test plan/cycles or experiences without using crowdsourcing?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6046/any-good-test-plan-cycles-or-experiences-without-using-crowdsourcing)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [What are the available multi platform test tools available for native mobile applications?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6035/what-are-the-available-multi-platform-test-tools-available-for-native-mobile-app)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Does Selenium's LoadableComponent make sense in a SPA (Single Page Application)?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6056/does-seleniums-loadablecomponent-make-sense-in-a-spa-single-page-application)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Manual tester wanting to get into automation](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/manual-tester-wanting-to-get-into-automation)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Teaching Quality Assurance (QA) Methods](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6129/teaching-quality-assurance-qa-methods)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Nunit not working](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6108/nunit-not-working)

  **Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 4)
- [Test Automation in Agile?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6134/test-automation-in-agile)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)